# Add ip to ipset with port

Tags: iptables, ipset

I would like to block IPs when connectioning on a given port, e.g. 1.1.1.1 on port 443.

I create the ipset like this:

```
sudo ipset -N blockdaily nethash maxelem 2500000
```

I can add an IP to it like this:

```
add blockdaily 1.1.1.1
```

But when I try and block a port with this:

```
add blockdaily 1.1.1.1,443
```

I get an error:

```
ipset v6.34: Error in line 1: Syntax error: Elem separator in 1.1.1.1,443, but settype hash:net supports none.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To use the port number, you should create appropriate the hash type.

`ipset create blockdaily hash:ip,port`

2. You can add elements with similar commands:

```
ipset add blockdaily 1.1.1.1,tcp:443
ipset add blockdaily 1.1.1.1,udp:53
```

Comment: Anton Danilov, Спасибо.